# Free-form screenshots on Mac

Tags: screen-capture

I know I can take screenshots of regions using the cmd + shift + 3/4/5 keys on the Mac. But I want to be able to select a specific non-rectangular region to capture.

How do I capture freehand screenshots on the Mac?

I believe this feature is also called "polygon" or "free-form" snipping.

Additionally, I also know that I can take a large screenshot and then take free-form screenshots using Preview with the Lasso Selection tool. But I want to be able to take a freeform screenshot directly without having to use Preview intermediately.

Answer (score 4):

[Capto](https://www.globaldelight.com/capto/) can do free-form snipping. It has 3 modes of what it calls "area capture", namely Rectangle, Circle (which can be an elipse), and Freehand. As far as I can tell Freehand is only freeform, with no polygon option.

A simple example:

[image]